# Ordering clauses of a left join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join some tables with a query like below. Because I want to get the c.name ideally that the b table refers to. If the b table doesn't have rows in the result set or the b row doesn't refer to c, then just get the c.name that a table refers to.

```
SELECT a.*, c.name
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON (b.c_id IS NOT NULL AND b.c_id = c.id) OR a.c_id = c.id
```

However mysql is always joining c with `a.c_id = c.id` and getting the less-favored c.name. Is it possible to avoid this, or is mySQL trying to get a full result set as quick as it can?

Comment: You have some table definitions (as create table statements), test data (as insert statements) and expected output (as something easy to check). I really want to test your query but don't want to spend any time creating tables and test data. I can execute them in my SQL IDE quickly. Have you considered using http://sqlfiddle.com?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
SELECT a.*, c.name
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = COALESCE(b.c_id, a.c_id)
```

When `b.c_id` is NULL, then `a.c_id` will be used.  Otherwise `b.c_id` will be used.

It's not about speed.  `OR` will give you all possible result rows including both `b.c_id` and `a.c_id` mappings for each row in `a`.

If you're not familiar with `COALESCE()`, the long form of this is almost exactly like your query but using `IF()` instead of `OR`.

```
SELECT a.*, c.name
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON IF(b.c_id IS NOT NULL, b.c_id = c.id, a.c_id = c.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help:

```
SELECT a.*, c.name
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.b_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c ON (b.c_id IS NOT NULL OR b.c_id = c.id) OR a.c_id = c.id
```

Comment: That will give exponential number of matches.  Every row in `b` that isn't `NULL` will match every row in `c`.

Comment: Just remove b.c_id iS NOT NULL if he doesn't want to